# Flutter: A RenderFlex overflowed by 14 pixels on the bottom

Tags: flutter

My app has a bottom navigation bar that shows or hides according to the direction of the scrolling:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';


class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  // The item list where the data is stored.
  List<String> items = []; 
  // Flags used to check the loading status.
  bool loading = false, allLoaded = false;

  // Function that loads data in the item list.
  mockFetch() async {
    // No more data to load.
    if (allLoaded) {
      return;
    }   

    // Set the loading flag to true to prevent this function to be called several times.
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    }); 

    // Simulates the delay that might occurs during an API call.
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500));

    // If the item list is higher or equal to 60, an empty array is returned to simulate
    // the end of the data stream. If not, 20 more items are generated. 
    List<String> newData = items.length >= 60 ? [] : List.generate(20, (index) => "List Item ${index + items.length}");

    // Add the new data to the item list.
    if (newData.isNotEmpty) {
      items.addAll(newData);
    }

    // Reset the flags.
    setState(() {
      loading = false;
      // Returns false if the array is empty.
      allLoaded = newData.isEmpty;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Call the mockFetch() function when the state of MyHomePage is initialized for the first time.
    mockFetch();
    // Set a listener.
    _scrollController.addListener(() {

      if (_scrollController.position.pixels >= _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent && !loading) {
        mockFetch();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _scrollController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
        title: Text("Home Page"),
      ),
      body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
        if (items.isNotEmpty) {
          return Stack(
            // Dispay the data.
            children: [
              ListView.separated(
                // Assign the scroll controller to the ListView.
                controller: _scrollController,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  // Display the newly loaded items.
                  if (index < items.length) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(items[index]),
                    );
                  }
                  // An extra item has been added to the index of the list meaning that
                  // all the items have been loaded.
                  else {
                    // Inform the user that there is no more data to load.
                    return Container(
                      width: constraints.maxWidth,
                      height: 50,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text("Nothing more to load"),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
              },
              // Add a separator between each item.
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Divider(height: 1);
              },
              // Add an extra item to the length of the list when all of the items are loaded.
              itemCount: items.length + (allLoaded ? 1 : 0)),

              if (loading)...[
                // Display a progress indicator at the bottom of the list whenever some data is loading.
                Positioned(
                  left: 0,
                  bottom: 0,
                  child: Container(
                    width: constraints.maxWidth,
                    height: 80,
                    child: Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    ),
                  )
                )
              ]
            ],
          );
        }
        else {
          return Container(
            child: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          );
        }

      }
    ),

      bottomNavigationBar: AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: _scrollController,
        builder: (context, child) {
          return AnimatedContainer(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            height: _scrollController.hasClients && _scrollController.position.userScrollDirection == ScrollDirection.reverse ? 0: 100,
            child: child,
          );  
        },  
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.amber[200],
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              label: 'Home',
            ),  
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.child_friendly),
              label: 'Child',
            ),  
          ],  
        ),  
      ),  
    ); // Scaffold
  }
```

But when the bottom navigation bar shows or hides I get the following error

> A RenderFlex overflowed by 14 pixels on the bottom.

I tried to use `Expanded`, `Flexible`, `SingleChildScrollView` with the bottom navigation bar but I still gets this error.
Can someone show me how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return AnimatedContainer(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            height: _scrollController.hasClients && _scrollController.position.userScrollDirection == ScrollDirection.reverse ? 0 : kBottomNavigationBarHeight,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              child: BottomNavigationBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.amber[200],
                items: const [
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                    label: 'Home',
                  ),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.child_friendly),
                    label: 'Child',
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can achieve using of `hidable 1.0.3`  package for achieve the functionality.**

**Full Code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:hidable/hidable.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  // The item list where the data is stored.
  List<String> items = [];
  // Flags used to check the loading status.
  bool loading = false, allLoaded = false;

  // Function that loads data in the item list.
  mockFetch() async {
    // No more data to load.
    if (allLoaded) {
      return;
    }

    // Set the loading flag to true to prevent this function to be called several times.
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    });

    // Simulates the delay that might occurs during an API call.
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500));

    // If the item list is higher or equal to 60, an empty array is returned to simulate
    // the end of the data stream. If not, 20 more items are generated.
    List<String> newData = items.length >= 60 ? [] : List.generate(20, (index) => "List Item ${index + items.length}");

    // Add the new data to the item list.
    if (newData.isNotEmpty) {
      items.addAll(newData);
    }

    // Reset the flags.
    setState(() {
      loading = false;
      // Returns false if the array is empty.
      allLoaded = newData.isEmpty;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Call the mockFetch() function when the state of MyHomePage is initialized for the first time.
    mockFetch();
    // Set a listener.
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels >= _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent && !loading) {
        mockFetch();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _scrollController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
        title: Text("Home Page"),
      ),
      body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
        if (items.isNotEmpty) {
          return Stack(
            // Dispay the data.
            children: [
              ListView.separated(
                  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                  // Assign the scroll controller to the ListView.
                  controller: _scrollController,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    // Display the newly loaded items.
                    if (index < items.length) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(items[index]),
                      );
                    }
                    // An extra item has been added to the index of the list meaning that
                    // all the items have been loaded.
                    else {
                      // Inform the user that there is no more data to load.
                      return Container(
                        width: constraints.maxWidth,
                        height: 50,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text("Nothing more to load"),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                  // Add a separator between each item.
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Divider(height: 1);
                  },
                  // Add an extra item to the length of the list when all of the items are loaded.
                  itemCount: items.length + (allLoaded ? 1 : 0)),
              if (loading) ...[
                // Display a progress indicator at the bottom of the list whenever some data is loading.
                Positioned(
                    left: 0,
                    bottom: 0,
                    child: Container(
                      width: constraints.maxWidth,
                      height: 80,
                      child: Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      ),
                    ))
              ]
            ],
          );
        } else {
          return Container(
            child: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          );
        }
      }),
      bottomNavigationBar: Hidable(
        controller: _scrollController,
        wOpacity: false,
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 200,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: BottomNavigationBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.amber[200],
            items: const [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                label: 'Home',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.child_friendly),
                label: 'Child',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ); // Scaffold
  }
}
```

Comment: Answer working for you??

Comment: Can you try this?? Duddy67

Answer (score 1):

Try below code and wrap your `BottomNavigationBar` inside `SizedBox` and give it to height on your need, Wrap `SizedBox` inside `SingleChildScrollView` as well.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
      child: SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .15,
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.amber[200],
          items: const [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              label: 'Home',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.child_friendly),
              label: 'Child',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score -1):

**I'm Trying to Solve your Problem:**

*To fix this issue, you can try wrapping the ListView with an Expanded widget:*

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: ListView.separated(
        controller: _scrollController,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          // ...
        },
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Divider(height: 1);
        },
        itemCount: items.length + (allLoaded ? 1 : 0),
      ),
    ),
    if (loading) ...[
      // ...
    ],
  ],
),
```